# Reactive ToProperty not setting property

Tags: viewmodel, observable, reactiveui

I have the property Sessions in my vm

```
private ObservableAsPropertyHelper<IEnumerable<SessionViewModel>> _Sessions;
public IEnumerable<SessionViewModel> Sessions
{
    get { return _Sessions.Value; }
}
```

I am trying to set this in the constructor like so

```
this.WhenAny(x => x.LocationsViewModel.CurrentLocation, x => x.Date, (location, date) => location.Value)
        .Where(x => x != null)
        .Select(x => FilterSessions(x.Id, Date))
        .ToProperty(this, x => x.Sessions);
```

FilterSessions looks like so

```
private IEnumerable<SessionViewModel> FilterSessions(Guid locationId, DateTime date)
{
     return _allSessions
        .Where(s => s.SessionLocationId == locationId && s.StartTime.Date == date.Date)
        .Select(s => new SessionViewModel(s));
}
```

It returns 10 SessionViewModel's but _Sessions is never set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What platform is this? Certain platforms do not allow setting private fields via reflection. Instead, you can just use the return value of ToProperty:

```
_Sessions = this.WhenAny(x => x.LocationsViewModel.CurrentLocation, x => x.Date, (location, date) => location.Value)
        .Where(x => x != null)
        .Select(x => FilterSessions(x.Id, Date))
        .ToProperty(this, x => x.Sessions);
```

Or better, in RxUI 5.x:

```
this.WhenAny(x => x.LocationsViewModel.CurrentLocation, x => x.Date, (location, date) => location.Value)
        .Where(x => x != null)
        .Select(x => FilterSessions(x.Id, Date))
        .ToProperty(this, x => x.Sessions, out _Sessions);
```

Comment: WinRT is the platform. My workaround was slightly different, I'll post it as a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this by settings the property in the subscribe method like so:

```
this.WhenAny(x => x.LocationsViewModel.CurrentLocation, x => x.Date, (location, date) => location.Value)
        .Where(x => x != null)
        .Select(x => FilterSessions(x.Id, Date))
        .Subscribe(x => Sessions = x);
```

Comment: The advantage of using ToProperty here is that it guarantees that even if FilterSessions runs code on another thread, Sessions will be assigned on the UI thread (but this also works)